# Importing from parallel folders in Python 3. How to do it nicely?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

```
src\
    code\
         classes.py
         __init__.py
    test\
         tester.py
```

I have the following directory layout. I want to be able to run `python tester.py` as my driver command. `tester.py` would like to import some function or class from `classes.py`. I'm unable to do this for some reason. I tried doing relative imports, and a whole lot of other ideas, to the point of confusion now of what I'm doing. I would like a succinct way to do this. I've been able to do this if `tester.py` is a directory above `classes.py`, but I would like to have two separate folders in parallel like so. Any ideas?

Comment: "I tried doing relative imports" We can only tell you why this didn't work if you show us how you tried. However, you might want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this isn't how the Python import system works.  Python imports modules (or parts or modules), rather than classes directly.

There is a full really good post here that details scripts vs modules and imports in full
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14132912/2961873

Comment: While what you say is true, I think you've missed the point. OP complains of not being able to do the import at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can always set environment variable `PYTHONPATH` to point to directory `src` allowing you to then import from package `code`. But an alternative would be to add the following code to the beginning of `tester.py` that adds whatever is the parent directory of the directory in which `tester.py` resides to the system path at runtime:

```py
import os.path
import sys

# go up one directory level from this file's directory:
path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))
# prepend parent directory to the system path:
sys.path.insert(0, path)

# now you can import from package code:
from code.classes import SomeClass
```